# How to check if a Document Library (SPDocumentLibrary) supports a particular ContentType

Tags: linq, sharepoint-2010

I have a SharePoint 2010 site set up locally for debugging with the following topography:

```
Main (SPSite)
 -> Toolbox (SPWeb)
    -> MyTool (SPWeb)
```

I have created and deployed the following to Main:

1. Custom Field "RequestedBy"
2. Custom Field "OriginalRequestFileName"
3. Custom Content Type "RequestContentType" that contains the above two fields in addition to OOB fields
4. Custom List Definition "RequestListDefinition" based on the above ContentType
5. VisualWebPart "MyFileUploaderWebPart" that has a custom EditorPart to allow the user to define which document library the file should be uploaded to.

I have created an instance of a list "My Request List" in MyTool that's based on my custom list definition "RequestListDefinition".

In the EditorPart I've got a drop-down list of document libraries.

```
 private void PopulateDocumentLibraryList(DropDownList dropDownList)
    {
        SPWeb currentWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;

        SPListCollection lists = currentWebsite.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);
        if (lists.Count > 0)
        {
            List<SPDocumentLibrary> docLibraries = lists.Cast<SPList>()
                .Select(list => list as SPDocumentLibrary)
                .Where(library => library != null && !library.IsCatalog && !library.IsSiteAssetsLibrary)
                .ToList();

            dropDownList.DataSource = docLibraries;
            dropDownList.DataTextField = "Title";
            dropDownList.DataValueField = "ID";
            dropDownList.DataBind();

            // Default the selected item to the first entry
            dropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
```

I would like to restrict the list of document libraries to only those that are derived from my custom list definition that I've deployed. I thought of doing this by checking the supported content types and thus tried altering the Where clause to:

```
private void PopulateDocumentLibraryList(DropDownList dropDownList)
{
    SPWeb currentWebsite = SPContext.Current.Web;

    SPListCollection lists = currentWebsite.GetListsOfType(SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary);
    if (lists.Count > 0)
    {   
        SPContentType voucherRequestListContentType = currentWebsite.ContentTypes["VoucherRequestContentType"];
        List<SPDocumentLibrary> docLibraries = lists.Cast<SPList>()
            .Select(list => list as SPDocumentLibrary)
            .Where(library => library != null && !library.IsCatalog && !library.IsSiteAssetsLibrary && library.IsContentTypeAllowed(voucherRequestListContentType))
            .ToList();

        dropDownList.DataSource = docLibraries;
        dropDownList.DataTextField = "Title";
        dropDownList.DataValueField = "ID";
        dropDownList.DataBind();

        // Default the selected item to the first entry
        dropDownList.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

It bombs out with the following error though:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ct 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ct

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: ct]
   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList.IsContentTypeAllowed(SPContentType ct) +26981638
   Dominos.OLO.WebParts.FileUploader.<>c__DisplayClass7.<PopulateDocumentLibraryList>b__4(SPDocumentLibrary library) +137
   System.Linq.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() +269
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +578
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +78
   Dominos.OLO.WebParts.FileUploader.DocumentLibrarySelectorEditorPart.PopulateDocumentLibraryList(DropDownList dropDownList) +801
   Dominos.OLO.WebParts.FileUploader.DocumentLibrarySelectorEditorPart.CreateChildControls() +154
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +146
   Dominos.OLO.WebParts.FileUploader.DocumentLibrarySelectorEditorPart.SyncChanges() +102
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.ToolPane.OnSelectedWebPartChanged(Object sender, WebPartEventArgs e) +283
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.WebPartEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, WebPartEventArgs e) +0
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.BeginWebPartEditing(WebPart webPart) +96
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.ShowToolPaneIfNecessary() +579
   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPWebPartManager.OnPageInitComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) +296
   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.UI.Page.OnInitComplete(EventArgs e) +11056990
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1674
```

This suggests to me that it's failing to find the content type.

Another thought I had was to try and retrieve all lists that are of my custom list definition type "RequestListDefinition". However, SPWeb.GetListsOfType() takes an  SPListTemplateType, which is an enum and thus doesn't contain my custom list definition. The documentation for SPListTemplateType (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx) suggests using a method that accepts a string or an int instead of SPListTemplateType but I haven't seen any documentation for this.

Can someone please help me work out either:

1. how I can get just those lists that are derived from my custom list definition; or
2. how I can get a hold of my custom content type; or
3. point me in the direction of a better solution for restricting the list of SPDocumentLibrary?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

**Point 2:**

The `SPContentType` should be retrieved via `currentWebsite.AvailableContentTypes[name]`. The `ContentTypes` property of a `SPWeb` does only return content types created on this particular web. However, `AvailableContentTypes` does return all content types available in the current site collection.

**Update:**
To check whether the list has your content type, you should use the content type collection on the list:

```
SPContentTypeId ctId = voucherRequestListContentType.Id;

// LINQ where clause:
.Where(library => (...) && library.ContentTypes[ctID] != null);
```

The method `SPList.IsContentTypeAllowed` checks if a given content type is **supported** on the list and not if the content type is part of the list. See the MSDN documentation [SPList.IsContentTypeAllowed Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms460619.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, Stefan :) That seems to have successfully found the ContentType. Unfortunately adding the IsContentTypeAllowed() call to the where clause didn't give me the results I was hoping for. The "Site Pages" document library is still showing up in my drop down of Document Libraries.

Comment: updated the question regarding the `IsContentTypeAllowed` issue.

Comment: That resulted in no Document Libraries being returned :/

Answer (score 0):

I found that `IsApplicationList` (SP 2013) was helpful in limiting to Document Libraries that were non-system libraries (i.e. `IsApplicationList`  is true for _catalogs, SiteAssets, and SitePages, but not for Shared Documents).

In PowerShell, you can see this by running the following

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$site = Get-SPSite "http://sharePoint2013Url" 
$webs = $site.AllWebs
foreach($web in $webs)
{
    Write-Host "$($web.Url)"
    foreach($list in $web.GetListsOfType([Microsoft.SharePoint.SPBaseType]::DocumentLibrary))
    {
       Write-Host "$($list.DefaultEditFormUrl)  $($list.IsApplicationList)"
    }
}
```